# TDS failing with "Sitecore Deploy Path & Sitecore Web point to the same location"

Tags: tds

I have setup an application in my local where I am trying to Sync with TDS. I am facing the following issue as shown in the screen shot.

1. I have provided the Sitecore Deploy Path & Sitecore Web URL Path which should match my locally hosted IIS site.

[image: TDS Sync is Getting Failed Screen Shot]

Comment: Open the Output window in Visual Studio, then switch "Show output from" to "Team Development for Sitecore". What errors do you see there?

Comment: Can you show your host file? Also screen shot your bindings in iis, and the settings which shows which folder your directing it too? Also above can you show the full sitecore web url + sitecore deploy url. ?

Comment: Simple and easy step you might have missed, Save the changes you made to Website Url and Deploy path and run test

Comment: Always run the Visual Studio in admin mode to prevent such errors :)

Answer (score 14):

Do you run Visual Studio in Admin mode? Recently I had the same issue and it was related to some URL Rewrite redirects which made TDS unable to complete its tests. You could use Fiddler to check that. You should see something like this:

[image: TDS test request]

Answer (score 4):

Well this could be one of many things, some suggestions or thoughts:

1. After you've updated the Website Url and Deploy path, make sure you have pressed ctrl + S to save the configuration, if you don't do this it won't work.
2. Go to your Website Url, and ensure you can actually login to Sitecore, if you can not, its failing because Sitecore isn't working and in that case you need to diagnose and fix Sitecore first.
3. Double check in IIS to see if that Website Url maps to that file system location.
4. Sometimes I have to restart Visual Studio, to get a Sync to work, this would probably be your last option, because it's probably not this, but it doesn't hurt to try it atleast.
5. Check the folder access permissions

I hope those suggestions help!

Answer (score 1):

When I have seen this before it is sometimes I am missing the \website part in the deploy folder path or if I have not logged into the Sitecore site before I have to do that first before doing the test connection. Also sometimes just exiting Visual Studio and going back in fixes it. It would help though if you post what the output window contents are.